# Detect Windows Automatic Updates

Tags: registry, windows-update, file-monitoring, file-in-use

I have software that replaces core OS files. Problem is that Microsoft updates replace those files, rendering the program inoperative. **How can I detect file replacement at boot time**, due to automatic updates?

My idea is a registry watch on some key, what key? Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boot-time file replacements are done by smss.exe by referring `PendingFileRenameOperations` value under `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager` key. Also, `AllowProtectedRenames` should be set to `1` if files that are protected by Windows File Protection are going to be moved/deleted. Few resources that might be helpful:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365240.aspx
http://www.techbytes.ca/techbyte101.html

Comment: I am not sure if `AllowProtectedRenames` is needed on Vista and above. Because there being no WFP.